# Ftell for text files

Tags: c, ftell

I use this little program to understand how ftell works. I created a txt file and i typed in "15" and below that, in a second line, "no".  So what I expected was it to print 0, then after it reads 15, print 2 and then since no is on the second line, meaning I have left a few "available spots" on the first line which i could have filled with more characters i would expect it to print definitely bigger number than 7 (which is what it actually printed). WHY?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int x;
    char box[10];

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    printf("%ld", ftell(fp));

    fscanf(fp,"%d",&x );
    printf("\n%ld", ftell(fp));

    fscanf(fp, "%s", box);
    printf("\n%ld\n", ftell(fp));
}
```

output:
0
2
7

Comment: Why would you expect a bigger number? And what is the number you expected? I would actually expect a *smaller* number (`5` or `6`, depending on platform): Two for `15`, one or two for the newline, then two more for `no`.

Comment: Why would you expect a number bigger than 7 when you've only read in at most 5 characters ("15" + \n + "no")

Comment: Can you provide a hexdump of your `test.txt`? With the information provided here, the `7` can not be explainted.

Answer (score 4):

There are nothing like *available slots* in a text file(*). It is just a mere sequence of characters, some of then being interpreted as an End Of Line (commonly `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`). So your text file should contain the following characters (assuming DOS/Windows EOL):

```
1 5 \r \n n o \r \n
```

This one should give for output: 0 2 6.

If you have 7 as the last value, you have probably a space somewhere, probably at the end of the first line (between `5` and `\r`).

---

At least on common OS, text files are represented as streams with line delimiters. Thanks to @JohnBollinger for noticing that other OS could have featured fixed lenght records text files

Comment: What's `\r`? I haven't seen that anywhere on my book.

Comment: @Giannis `\r` is a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, of course you're right about the OP's actual situation, but you are mixing two distinct concepts here.  There are no empty slots in a *stream*, but historically, some operating systems have featured (for example) text *file* formats with fixed-length records and no explicit line terminators, which do have a sense of empty slots.  The conversions required of C implementations working with files opened in text mode are not necessarily limited to line terminators.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: phew..., as a rather old dinosaur (programming since the late 70'); I thought I had practiced quite a range of old tools, including text editors processing fixed lenght logical lines, but never encountered fixed length text files! I have edited my post anyway...

Comment: Since it's `1 5 \r \n n o \r \n`, which means there are 8 characters, shouldn't it be 8 and not 6 (or 7 which I got)?

Comment: @Giannis: the `scanf` family functions stop reading on the first blank character, so when reading the second line, they stop before the end of line - the reason why you get 2 after reading first line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that your file contains:

```
"15\r\nno\r\n"
```

Then the first conversion reads in `1` (pos. 1) and `5` (pos. 2), then reads the carriage return `\r` (pos. 3), which it `ungetc()`s (pos. 2 again).

Then, the next string is read in (`no`) and the `\r` is hit, which is again pushed back into the stream, hence the position should be 6. To explain the 7, there has to be some extra blank between the `15` and the `no` (trailing or leading space for example).

So, speaking generally, the position is always the last char, that `*scanf()` converted. The next (non-matching) char has to be read in, but is pushed back into the stream.

Comment: "Then, the next string is read in (no) " --> Hmm, some detail:. 5 characters  "\r\nno\r" are read (no _string_) and then `'\r'` is put back,  The _string_ `"no"` is saved.